# Running a VPN service on my Desktop, but want to send sound-over-LAN to desktop from my laptop via VBAN. Is there a way to allow this?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn

I'm running Manjaro linux on my desktop, along with nordvpn for numerous connectivity reasons. I treat my spare windows laptop as a second monitor of sorts. To receive sound from this laptop, I have a script opens a VBAN protocol listening port 6980 on my linux desktop, and my windows laptop sends sound via the same port 6980 to the desktop's local IP. With the vpn disconnected, this works perfectly well.

Obviously when I connect the VPN though, this prevents that kind of routing on my LAN. I'm unaware of any way to circumvent this without a super fancy router - but I'm curious if anyone is aware of a workaround? Could I possibly limit the VPN connection to specific applications on my linux desktop and still allow it to listen to port 6980 on my LAN, sort of pre-VPN routing?

I should note that I don't have any application-aware networking hardware, just a basic ISP-provided hub and an ASUS router.

Thanks for any assistance or could point me in the right direction to look for more information.

Comment: Actually it's not a natural/inherit side effect. The VPN program you use has likely done something explicitly / (over-)aggressively to mask the LAN subnet route. Check with `ip r`, `ip ru`, `iptables-save` and `nft list ruleset` to find out what that is exactly and override it, or see if the program itself provides options for you to configure it not to.

Comment: @TomYan This was super helpful, I just whitelisted my internal subnet from the vpn routing table and its all working just fine. I thought there was some custom interface/route masking going on - turns out it was a much easier problem to solve. Thanks!